# SQLitePlugin with cordova and ANDROID

Tags: android, sqlite, plugins, cordova, multiple-databases

I need to use 2 sqlite database for my app
the 2 databases have the some structure because one of it is `StoricDB`
in some procedure i need to use both db.

i do this code:

```
var onDeviceReady = function ()
{
   testwith2db();
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

function testwith2db (){
var dbCurrent_path  = "/sdcard/Android/data/myDatabase/DbCurrent"
var dbStoric_poath  = "/sdcard/Android/data/myDatabase/DbStoric"

// this work fine
var db_current = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(dbCurrent_path , "1.0", "DbCurrent", 10000000);
db_current.transaction(doquerycurrent, on_tran_error, on_tran_success);


//this work fine
var db_storic = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(dbStoric_poath , "1.0", "DbStoric", 10000000);
db_storic.transaction(doquerystoric, on_tran_error, on_tran_success);

/*
 following lines are my problem 
 because if i do:... another query on currentdb, the query is alwais executed on last db opened 
 for me is impossible to use currentdb again
*/
var db_current = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(dbCurrent_path , "1.0", "DbCurrent", 10000000);
db_current.transaction(doquerycurrent, on_tran_error, on_tran_success);
}

function doquerycurrent(txc){

// strange behaviour
// this query is executed on storic db if a have opened it

txc.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table1", [],[]);

}
function doquerystoric(txs){

txs.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table1", [],[]);

}
```

i have tried with attach db form my query but is unsupported from android ????

```
tx.executeSql("ATTACH DATABASE '/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/myDatabase/DbStoric' as S",[], on_query_success)  // this line return error
```

please help me
thanks